# Writing a CardTrick program and I'm having troubles to see if the User's card is one of the seven random cards drawn from a deck

Tags: java

Everything about the code works fine until I add the last If statement in the Cardtrick class to see if the User card pick matches the seven random cards. When I don't run the If Statement, the code works as I expected and I see 7 random cards.  I added the Card class just in case you guys wanted to see it.

```
`package pickacard;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardTrick {

    public static void main(String[] args){
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Card[] magicHand = new Card[7];

        for (int i=0; i<magicHand.length; i++){

            Card c = new Card();

    c.setValue(c.randomValue());
    c.setSuit(Card.SUITS[c.randomSuit()]);
    magicHand[i] =c;
        }

        for (Card magicHand1 : magicHand) {
            System.out.println(magicHand1.getSuit() + " " + magicHand1.getValue());
        }
         System.out.println("Pick a card, any card");
        System.out.println("Pick the card value");

      int UserValue = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Pick the card suit");
                System.out.println("1 = Hearts, 2 = Diamonds, 3 = Spades, 4 = Clubs");

        int UserSuit = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your card is: " + UserValue + " of " + UserSuit);
                System.out.println("Let's see if your card is in the magic hand");

    if(UserValue== magicHand1.getValue() && UserSuit == magicHand1()){
    System.out.println("Great job");
     }
      }
      }





package pickacard;

/**
 * A class that models playing card Objects. Cards have 
 * a value (note that Ace = 1, Jack -11, Queen =12, King = 13)
 * A suit (clubs, hearts, spades, diamonds).
 * There are 52 cards in a deck, no jokers
 */
public class Card {

   private String suit; //clubs, spades, diamonds, hearts
   private int value;//1-13

   public static final String [] SUITS = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
    /**
     * @return the suit
     */
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * @param suit the suit to set
     */
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

public int randomSuit()
{
int value= (int)(Math.random()*4)+0;
return value;
}
public int randomValue()
{
int value= (int)(Math.random()*13)+1;   
return value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&& UserSuit == magicHand1()`

This is comparing an `int` with a `Card`.  You likely meant to check the value of `magicHand1.getSuit()`, but you'll need to make sure that the user input has been translated into one of the Strings you are using for `suit`.

Comment: Yeah I meant to write magicHand1.getSuit() but the code still doesn't work even if I just check the value and take out the "suit" part of the code

Comment: By "doesn't work" do you get an error or an unexpected result?  `magicHand1` is actually out of scope during your comparison  (it's only in scope during the `for (Card magicHand1 : magicHand) {` loop you have for printing out the values.  You'll need to loop through the array again to check against each card (unless you really just meant to check `magicHand[1]`).

Comment: I get an error when I don't put the if statement in the scope of the magicHand1. When I do have in the scope of the magicHand1, only one random card is shown instead of seven.

Comment: If you're just expanding the existing for loop in order to keep magicHand1 in scope, then yes, it will only have one Card in scope at a time.

You'll need to step through the array again.  You can wrap the if statement and the output in another `for (Card magicHand1 : magicHand) {}` loop.  Or, more correctly, you can use the values provided by the user to create a new `Card` and check if that card matches a value in the magicHand array (by using a method like the ones at https://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/check-if-array-contains-a-value-java/)